# Image gets bigger than a div container with a border and overflows

Tags: html, css, border

here's a simple problem for you to solve.
The image should be 90vw and the container should add a border to the image.

The border can't be applied directly to the image, since the image in further steps of coding will have some style directly applied to the html.

The current implementation causes the border to be smaller than the image. How can it wraps nicely around the image?

I really want something simple to keep it light and easy to understand for a newbie like me, so please no codes that do triple flips and pike jumps with gentle, graceful landings like I usually see on Stack Overflow.

HTML:

```
<div id="main-image-container-slideshow">
   <img id="main-image-slideshow" src="http://localhost:8888/image/jpeg/campus1.jpg">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#main-image-container-slideshow {
    border: 5px solid black;
}

#main-image-slideshow {
    width: 90vw;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would make the container be 90vw AND have the container have the border.  The image would then be the full width of the 90vw container.  I made the image a block to remove any potential unwanted space underneath.

```
#main-image-container-slideshow 
{   border: 5px solid black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 90vw;

/* If you want the container to be centered, add this, otherwise skip */
    margin: 0 auto;

}

#main-image-slideshow 
{
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Yes, the block is necessary, otherwise there is some space at the bottom.

Comment: Glad it worked.  Yeah, I almost always have images be blocks by default (unless they are emoji) because inline elements have that baseline which factors line-height into the height and can put that extra, unneeded space in.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `display` property of the wrapper to `flex` and set the `flex-direction` property to `column`. And, if you decide to change the width of the image, then you won't have to change the `display` property in CSS.

```css
#main-image-container-slideshow {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 2px solid white;
}

#img {
  width: 90vw;
}

html {
  background-color: black; /* sets the background color to black to make it easier to see the border */
}
```

```html
<div id="main-image-container-slideshow">
   <img id="main-image-slideshow" src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/wall-wallpaper-concrete-colored-   painted-textured-concept_53876-31799.jpg?size=626&ext=jpg">
</div>
```

The image used in the code snippet was found at [freepik](https://www.freepik.com/).

Comment: I've tried your settings, but the border is still smaller than the image.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the container width to 100vw and image width to 90% of the container's width which is equivalent to 90vw.

```css
.image-container {
  width: 100vw;
  border: 5px solid #000000;
}
.image {
  width: 90%;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-container">
      <img src="https://stackoverflow.design/assets/img/logos/so/logo-stackoverflow.png" class="image"/>
</div>
```

Comment: I've tried your settings, but now the border is bigger than the image on its right and on its bottom.